# another help with partial differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am to solve next task.

solve this PDE with boundary conditions.

$\Delta u = \frac{64}{r^5}\sin\varphi, \quad 1<r<2,$

$u'_r|_{r=1} = 2\cos^2\frac{\varphi}{2}, \quad u'_r|_{r=2} = 4\sin^2\frac{\varphi}{2}$

In my solution I am trying to search $u=w+v$, where $w=8\frac{1}{r^3}\sin\varphi$

(because $\Delta_{r,\varphi}w=\frac{64}{r^5}\sin\varphi$, that is my right part of the very first equation)

I will get for function $v(r,\varphi)$ next task with boundary conditions.

$\Delta v = 0$,

$v'_r|_{r=1} = 2\cos^2\frac{\varphi}{2}+24\sin\varphi=1+\cos\varphi+24\sin\varphi,$

$v'_r|_{r=2} = 4\sin^2\frac{\varphi}{2}+3/2\sin\varphi=2-2\cos\varphi+3/2\sin\varphi.$

Let's solve it!
we will try to search solution as $v=a\ln r+b+(cr+d/r)\cos\varphi+(er+f/r)\sin\varphi$ and $a,b,c,d,f,e$ are constants.

But take a look at the boundary conditions.

If you apply this to my function $v=a\ln r+...$ you will get $v'_r=a/r+...$

$a/1 = 1$ from the first condition and $a/2 = 2$ from the second... But $4\ne1$

So, does solution exist? Or do I make a mistake?

It upsets me. I also cannot understand conditions for existings of solutions for this PDE and cannot find it.

I don't have even answer for this task. It's just task to solve and show teacher. But it is strange to show him "not existing" or "not correct task" .

By the way, it is not important. I just want to know truth. Help me, please.

Comment: How did you get boundary conditions for $v$? The only function that should have BCs is $u$.

Comment: @Mattos I see that for $w=8\frac{1}{r^3}\sin\varphi$ I will get $\Delta_{r,\varphi}w=\frac{64}{r^5}\sin\varphi$. This is why it is useful to search solution as $u=w+v$. 

How did I get BC? 
Just $u'_r=(v+w)'_r $ and $w$ is known

Comment: You may want to add that to your post that you were searching for a solution of the form $u = v + w$. When I read your question, I had no idea you had tried that. Then again I could just be tired.

Answer (score 1):

Oh no, I was very tired. 
Of course condition of existing solutions here is not done.

because $2\cdot\int_0^{2\pi} 4\sin^2 (\varphi/2) d\varphi - 1\cdot \int 2\cos^2 (\varphi/2) d\varphi \ne 0.$

Here is incorrect task. I am sorry.